# lock and unlock sql server tables from .net code without using stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

I need to block a table from being accessed by any other process unless my current operation(usually a INSERT or an UPDATE) is completed, Is there a way to lock and unlock sql server tables from .net code without using stored procedures, i need these to avoid business rules based duplicate records from being entered into the table.

Comment: An sledge-hammer approach like this is **not going to scale**. You won't be able to support anything more than a very small number of concurrent users... Instead of this, you should define criteria to identify "duplicate" rows - and have a unique constraint on the table to prevent those duplicates.

Comment: The problem with defining a unique constraint is that a record is considered duplicate, only if it satisfies a number of conditions based on values in many number of tables. I couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: See my answer. You would use a transaction.  Can lock multiple tables in a transaction.  It could take a while to acquire multiple locks.  Echo comment 1 - not going to scale.  Please describe your situation where duplicate is based on multiple table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an use a hint

insert into table with (tablock) (colx) values ('newValuex');

If valuex is a primary key or has a unique constraint then it will be enforced.

But you don't need a tabloc to enforce that constraint.

If you have multiple statements then you can wrap them in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Better still, don't lock the tables (especially if it takes a long time to update/insert data), but commit changes only after all data is updated/inserted.

Comment: How does that stop two different processes from entering duplicate records ?

Comment: It will fail on commit, that is if you have primary keys and other constrains correctly defined.

Comment: As i said in my comment above, The problem with defining a unique constraint is that a record is considered duplicate, only if it satisfies a number of conditions based on values in many number of tables. I couldn't find a way to do that